# ui-router, factory share data

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Hy,

I want to share data between 1 component (NavBar) and other 1 ctrl (Ctrl1) in ui-view with factory, but it's not work.
When i modify factory in component or ctrl, it modify only his own scope. I want to share factory between ctrl and component.

HTML :

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <global-component></global-component>
 </div>
```

Javascript :

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [ 'ui.router']);

myApp.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
  $stateProvider.state("state1", {
    url: "#",
    template: "<p>State 1 </p> <input type=\"text\" ng-model=\"vm.b\"/> {{vm.b}}",
    controller: "Ctrl1",
    controllerAs: 'vm'
  }); 

   $urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function($injector, $location) {
    $injector.get('$state').go("state1");
    });
});

//Global Component
myApp.component('globalComponent', {
          template: 'Global controler </br> <nav-bar></nav-bar> <div ui-view></div>',
      controller: "GlobalCtrl",
      controllerAs: 'vm'
  });
myApp.controller('GlobalCtrl',function(Data){
  Data.test="test1";
});


//NavBar
myApp.component('navBar', {
      template: 'NavBar  <input type=\"text\" ng-model=\"vm.a\"/> {{vm.a}}',
      controller: "NavBarCtrl",
      controllerAs: 'vm'
  });

myApp.controller('NavBarCtrl',function(Data){
  var vm=this;
  vm.a=Data.test;
});

myApp.controller('Ctrl1',function(Data){
  var vm=this;
  Data.test="titi";
  vm.b=Data.test; 
});




myApp.factory('Data', function(){
  var data={};
  data.test="";
  return data;
});
```

The code :
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YrdvbV?editors=1111

Thanks

Comment: The controller declaration does not work that way. You should use ['Data', function(Data){}]. Si the service called 'Data' is injected in the controller, and received as the argument called Data.

Comment: The declaration work like this myApp.controller('NavBarCtrl',function(Data){, look the codepen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out working solution [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eGbxba?editors=1111).

The reason why it's wasn't working in the first palce is that you have changed the reference to `data` in your `setData` method. When the reference is changed, your are not working with the same object as before so this `vm.a=Data.getData();` is not bound to the same object as on initialization.

In your case, one way to resolve this is to wrap an object around your data (in the example provided, I used `data.item` instead of just data). Other options are to use `$watch` or something similar so values could be rebound to `ng-model`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's very simple finally :)